# Problem running the serial module with Python

Tags: python, serial

I am trying to use the serial port on the Raspberry but when I run the example below I have the message:

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

```py
import time
import serial

ser = serial.serial(
        port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
        baudrate = 9600,
        parity=0,
        stopbits=1,
        bytesize=8,
        timeout=1
)

while 1:
        ser.write('A')
        x=ser.readline()
        print (x)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Hi @Wagner Ideali, Welcome. Ah let me see.  Your edited program does not seem to match the earlier error message, therefore should mislead future readers. Anyway, I tried tracin back the original picture and reproduce your situation, but failed: https://imgur.com/gallery/1Rh4vVk.

Comment: Your original version seems to have a syntax/typo error of "serial.serial(...)" which should read "serial.Serial(...)".  So I tried to run your version 1 and got the same error as yours. So far so good. Now your version 2 have a new error.  I guess it is the serial/.write and serial readline error.  Anyway I have summarized version 1 and version 2 results in the following penzu link:https://penzu.com/p/350d51c9.  If you can confirm I have understood your question correctly, then I would move on  to compile my answer.  Cheers..

Comment: I removed the pyserial and re install it and running ok now

Comment: Thank you for your update. How nice to hear that problem solved. Cheers.

Comment: Hi tlfong01, I didnt understand very weel your comment above and so, I formatted the SD card, installed again the raspbian and re installed the pyserial and now is ok, but new problem is happen with pynput module and I put this problem in another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux and Python are case sensitive.

Try `ser = serial.Serial(`

Comment: Could you edit your question and cut&paste the full traceback?

Comment: @WagnerIdeali You should edit your question to add information, not add a comment.

Comment: @WagnerIdeali There is a link below your question named [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/105834/edit). Please click on it and add additional information to the question.